# Unicode value for right arrow with two strokes

Tags: unicode

I want to use the → character with two // strokes through the arrow but cannot find the unicode value for it anywhere. Does this exist in unicode? If not, is there a way to recreate it?

[image: Here's a snippet of a picture from the website on which I found the character.]

Comment: Like this one? *⇻* Oh wait... Solid arrow head required? *⭼*

Comment: The arrows you posted are italicized versions of ⇻. Unfortunately not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Ye, it was the closest I could do. As for creating your own.. Make a font with the glyphs as you expect?

Answer (score 1):

There are six Unicode characters whose name matches a right arrow with a double stroke, making use of the regular expression: `/right.*arrow.*double.*stroke/`.

[image: Unicode Data Finder > Find by Name]

Only two characters appear to be relevant candidates:

- ⇻ U+21FB  RIGHTWARDS ARROW WITH DOUBLE VERTICAL STROKE
- ⭼ U+2B7C  RIGHTWARDS TRIANGLE-HEADED ARROW WITH DOUBLE HORIZONTAL STROKE
  (* RIGHTWARDS TRIANGLE-HEADED ARROW WITH DOUBLE VERTICAL STROKE)

Notes:

- The official Unicode name of U+2B7C was initially wrong, but a corrected name has been added later as an alias.
- U+2B7C appears to be quite uncommon, no suitable font was available in the OS used for the screenshot. Still, it is possible to see what it should look like in the [Miscellaneous Symbols and Arrows - Range: 2B00–2BFF](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2B00.pdf) PDF document:

[image: Glyph for U+2B7C]

Answer (score 0):

I was not successful in finding what you were looking for (negative result).  U+0219B is a "Rightwards Arrow with Stroke" and U+021FB "Rightwards Arrow with Double Vertical Stroke".  If it exist, it would probably be called "Rightwards Arrow with Double Stroke".  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow_(symbol)

Answer (score 0):

The following Unicode sequences should describe your character, but unfortunately fonts are not helping.

- →⃫ : `\u2192\u20EB`
- ⟶⃫ : `\u27F6\u20EB`

They are normal and long arrow, with the combining U+20EB: COMBINING LONG DOUBLE SOLIDUS OVERLAY (long double slash overlay). You may find a technical font which can display both in the expected way.

You may get something acceptable also with:

- ⎯⎯⎯⃫⟶ `\u23AF\u23AF\u23AF\u20EB\u27F6` (using arrow extension line)
- ⎯⎯⃫⟶ `\u23AF\u23AF\u20EB\u27F6`

Depending on the environment, one of the two seem much better (on my computers).

So: you can express it (semantically) with Unicode, but standards fonts are not helping us. You should experiment with many symbols/mathematical fonts, to get an acceptable solution.

As alternative, you can build such image easily with SVG (and use a SVG as character image).